# Are character lists different than Strings in Idris?

Tags: idris

In Haskell, the following will print "hello": `putStrLn (['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'])`, however, this results in the compile error in Idris:

```
48 | main = do
   |        ~~ ...
When checking right hand side of main with expected type
        IO ()

When checking an application of function Prelude.Interactive.putStrLn:
        Can't disambiguate since no name has a suitable type:
                Prelude.List.::, Prelude.Stream.::
```

My suspicion is that this is because `String` is a builtin in Idris, but not in Haskell. Still, could a a typeclass be used in Idris to treat `List Char` as an instance of `String` (were `String` a type class)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's right, strings are not the same as list of characters in Idris. But there are functions that allow you to turn list of characters into a string and vice versa.

[unpack](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/prelude/Prelude/Strings.idr#L180) turns a string into a list of characters

[pack](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/prelude/Prelude/Strings.idr#L186) function turns a Foldable of characters into a string

Thus, in order to print list of characters, you just need:

```
putStrLn $ pack ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```